# Zookeeper Setup for 2 Rack failover handling

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to understand the impact and design for zookeeper setup since Kafka is dependent on zookeeper for its operations.

Zookeeper specifies 2F+1 no of nodes to be setup for reliable fault tolerance. Consider that If I have 2 racks and I setup 4 nodes on rack A and 5 on rack B (Total 9 zookeeper nodes) and rack B goes down (5 zookeeper nodes goes down). In that case with the requirement of 2F+1, it needs 11 zookeeper nodes where as I have only 9 nodes. So zookeeper in case of rack failure with higher no of nodes will not be able to sustain which will impact Kafka cluster behavior.

Can you please provide your inputs on how to better setup zookeeper so that Kafka can work seamlessly in case of 2 rack infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Since zookeeper cluster needs a quorum, with 2 racks, no matter the number of zookeeper instances, you can't achieve tolerance of one entire rack going down. You can, however, achieve that with 3 racks and an equal number of zookeeper instances on each rack.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you clarify what do you mean when you say that it needs equal number of zookeeper instances on each rack. Do you mean that if i have 3 rack setup i cannot single setup zookeeper ensemble with 4 znodes on rack A, 3 znodes on rack B and 2 on rack C ?

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as any one rack doesn't have more than half the nodes. I oversimplified it - you're right. Btw, a znode is a node in  zookeeper's data tree. It's not a zookeeper server instance.